# How to run a SQL Script that builds my DB and schema in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDB 2.0.2. I'm writing a SQL script that will create a new DB, construct the schema, and then populate the DB with static initial data. I know that the database will be automatically created if I simply start loading data, and that classes will automatically be created if I start inserting records, but I want to make sure that my classes have the right inheritance and Properties and Indexes before I begin my data load.

The SQL syntax is easy - I just need to know how to run the SQL script from the command line in order to instantiate the the DB, as if I were deploying a new instance of my DB at a new location, or for a new customer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you installed OrientDB in the base directory `ORIENTDB_HOME`, then go to the `$ORIENTDB_HOME/bin` directory. In this directory, execute the OrientDB SQL Script with the simple command:

*nux:

```
$ ./console.sh myscript.osql
```

Windows:

```
> console.bat myscript.osql
```

`mysql.osql` is a simple text file, containing all SQL command (`.oslq` is a typical file extension for OrientDB SQL scripts).

See [documentation](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Console-Command-Create-Database.html) for details how to create a new database. Example:

```
CREATE DATABASE plocal:/usr/local/orient/databases/demo/demo
```

or

```
CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/trick root verySecretPassword
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That worked like a champ. This will allow me to build up my database creation and initialization script outside the operational environment and source control it, just like other databases I work with regularly. Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: I tried this with OrientDB 2.1.3 but I get `!Unrecognized command: cmds.osql`Did it change or do I make any mistakes? According to the docs, it should still work.

Comment: @user3127060 it only works launching the command inside $ORIENTDB_HOME/bin

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest doc, you can do below:

1. `sh console.sh`
2. `orientdb> LOAD SCRIPT /path/to/scripts/data.osql`

Here is the link: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.1.x/console/Console-Command-Load-Script.htm